Given a ub_result structure returned by an unbound dns query, what ldns function will parse the result?
The unbound DNS resolver returns a DNS result that looks like this:
    struct ub_result {
        char* qname; /* text string, original question */
        int qtype;   /* type code asked for */
        int qclass;  /* class code asked for */
        char** data; /* array of rdata items, NULL terminated*/
        int* len;    /* array with lengths of rdata items */
        char* canonname; /* canonical name of result */
        int rcode;   /* additional error code in case of no data */
        void* answer_packet; /* full network format answer packet */
        int answer_len; /* length of packet in octets */
        int havedata; /* true if there is data */
        int nxdomain; /* true if nodata because name does not exist */
        int secure;  /* true if result is secure */
        int bogus;   /* true if a security failure happened */
        char* why_bogus; /* string with error if bogus */
    };

Using the ldns library, what API call should be used to parse the data field above?
Most specifically, what series of API calls will turn the data field above into into a parsed TLSA record?
The ldns documentation describes how to create a TLSA record from scratch, but what's missing is the function that does the opposite.
